# Filtering record from last month and current year

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this query, this one works fine, the thing is that it returns me everything from `ingresos`. I need to retrieve only the records of the last month and the current year.

I have tried `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` but it returns me a previous month based on today's day. 
I need the records of the last month without counting from the first to the last date.

This one is when e the page is loaded first:

```
SELECT * from ingresos
where fechaReporteING < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) DAY)
```

and this one is when the user selects a specific month:

```
SELECT * from ingresos
where fechaReporteING < DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),"-",'.$_POST['mes'].',"-","0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It used PHP to calculate the date based on the month selected by the user.

```
<?php
//Get your users month.
$month = isset($_GET['mes'])? $_GET['mes'] : "04";
//Starting date string `current year`-`user month`-`first day`
$startDateText = date('Y') . "-" . $month . "-01";

//Add one month to the starting date.
$startDate = date_create($startDateText);
$endDate = date_add($startDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 month'));

//String representation of the date
$endDateText = date_format($endDate, 'Y-m-d');

echo "<br><br>Search for records on or after $startDateText but before $endDateText.<br><br>";

$query = "SELECT * FROM ingresos
    WHERE fechaReportING >= '$startDateText' && fechaReportING < '$endDateText' ";

$allData = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query) or printf(mysqli_error($db_conx));
$totalDataRows = mysqli_num_rows($allData);
....
....
?>
```